# Only number in TEdit, Delphi

Tags: delphi

How can I add a `TEdit` that only accept numbers?
I search information but nothing helps me.

I need a `TEdit` that does not accept any letter or strings.

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char); 
begin 
  if not (Key in [#8, '0'..'9', DecimalSeparator]) then 
  begin
     ShowMessage('Invalid key: ' + Key); 
     Key := #0; 
  end 
  else 
  if (Key = DecimalSeparator) and (Pos(Key, Edit1.Text) > 0) then 
  begin 
    ShowMessage('Invalid Key: twice ' + Key); 
    Key := #0; 
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: I see you've had an answer about modern Delphi versions.  If you're using an earlier version, read about "Edit masks" in the OLH.

Comment: My users (and myself too) don't like controls to not accept any input. Instead they want some feedback that the input in a field is invalid. To accommodate this, I add a KeyPress event that checks that the field is valid (not just for numbers), change the background colour to yellow if it isn't and disable any buttons that require this field to be valid. Additionally sometimes I add a message (e.g. in the status bar) that explains what kind of input is expected.

Comment: in the properties tab underneath ''**name**'' you can select ''**NumbersOnly**.'' if you set this to _true_ you get the same effect without a lot of typing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In modern Delphi versions (D2009+) you can use the 
[TEdit.NumbersOnly](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit.NumbersOnly) property.

> Allows only numbers to be typed into the text edit.
>   Use NumbersOnly to prohibit entry of non-numeric characters in the textfield. Note, however, that a user can paste non-numeric characters in the textfield even when this property is set.

Another option is to use the [TMaskEdit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Mask.TMaskEdit) component.
An `EditMask` property using following characters can produce a valid numeric input, including negative values.

```
# : Accepts an optional sign or numeric digit
0 : Accepts a numeric character
9 : Accepts an optional numeric character
```

Comment: And `SetWindowLong/GWL_STYLE/ES_NUMBER` for old Delphi versions. Note that these solutions are for positive integers only.

Answer (score 1):

For older Delphi versions, i.e. 2006, (after @MBo hint), the code can be like this (can be put to Form.OnCreate):

```
CurrentStyle := GetWindowLong(Edit1.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
CurrentStyle := CurrentStyle or ES_NUMBER;
SetWindowLong(Edit1.Handle, GWL_STYLE, CurrentStyle);
```