# how to avoid spaces in tmaskedit?

Tags: delphi

Im having an issue with edit box. i need to be able to write positive and negative numbers ( 0.22 included)

i tried tedit numbers only feature but obviously i cant write negative sign. then i found tmaskedit that lets me write possitive and negative numbers but there are spaces and instead of for example 123 i can write 12 3  and get an error.

is there any quick way to solve this problem with spaces in tmaskedit or should i just try to write something with ifs and key presses?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only number in TEdit, Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753954/only-number-in-tedit-delphi)

Comment: yeah its a tmaskedit solution and there will be spaces when i type something. i used that solution until i noticed those spaces. thanks for the answer though

Comment: One option is to clean up the data (remove spaces) in the OnExit event with something like : `TMaskEdit(Sender).EditText := StringReplace(TMaskEdit(Sender).EditText,' ','',[rfReplaceAll]);` or similar before assigning the contents to a number.

Comment: The `CC` in the mask allows any printable character (which includes spaces). You might try to change them to `##` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was this function right here. and i went back to tedit box because i cant really get rid of spaces in tmaskedit

```
procedure KeyPressWithDouble(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not(Key in [#8, '0' .. '9', '-', FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator]) and
    not(ord(Key) = VK_RETURN) then
  begin
    showmessage('Invalid key');
    // Discard the key
    Key := #0;
  end;

end;
```